# Alias entry in LDAP and fetching alias data

Tags: ldap, spring-ldap

I am completely new in LDAP. I am not getting how to create alias in LDAP. I am using Spring-LDAP template in my project. 
My scenario is : Imran Khan can be found under Sports as well as Politics. I want to create alias entry against "Imran Khan" political links with sports. Can a single LDAP query server both normal entry and alias entry. Or I have to write two different queries for this purpose. If it is any of these, please help me with the proper query. Also in case of fetching result from the alias entries, what would be the query.
  Any help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Can a single LDAP query serve both normal entry and alias entry.

Yes, if its scope and search arguments are sufficient to access the entries in both places. However aliases are normally resolved automatically, so the result should be two copies of the same entry, the original (non-alias) one.

> Or I have to write two different queries for this purpose.

No.

> Also in case of fetching result from the alias entries, what would be the query.

The alias entry isn't returned at all. The original one is. You don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That was helpful indeed. But few thing, i need to be clear from your side.First, according to your suggestion, i assume, we do not have to bother about the alias entry if the correct method with parameter is there. If this is true, just let me know one thing, we are using ldapTemplate.bind("o=test1", null, personAttributes) for ldap entry, how should we use this mathed for alias entry also?

Comment: @Raktim I don't understand your assumption or your question. If you are asking how to create an alias, the answer is that you have to use the aliasedObject class and set its attributes accordingly.

Comment: Hi, again thanks for your response. As, iam just a beginner on LDAP, i even did not know how to create alias entry(as i said earlier post). Now from your suggestion, it is clear, i have to use "aliasedObject" class for this purpose. That would be good, if you just give me an example or a link about how to do that. Thanks very much...